# MathJax on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, meta

Should/Can we have MathJax on meta? It would be useful to implement stuff like [this proposal](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1116/7433).

I *do* know the argument that it makes pageloading slow, so I propose that it only be enabled if a post has `$turn_mathjax_on$` or something on it. I wrote a simple script that accomplishes this. There are two versions: http://jsfiddle.net/2tccA/1/ (only gives the turn-mathjax-on ability for posts), and http://jsfiddle.net/2tccA/2/ (has an uncommentable option to enable it for comments as well). For some reason, the mathjax main server is down atm, so neither of these are currently working. They should work when http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js no longer shown an error.

Unfortunately, neither of these scripts work for the editing auto-update preview. I don't think it should be too hard to code it, though..

Anyways, any comments or arguments for/against?

Comment: As I recall, MathJax doesn't work on chat either. Then one could extend the proposal to both meta and chat.

Comment: @Qmechanic no, they won't enable it on chat.. I'll find the MSO and/or math.SE thread on that tomorrow, I recall reading them..

Comment: @Qmechanic: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1088/  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97938/

Answer (score 10):

Typically if MathJax is enabled on the main site, we turn it on for meta too. I'm not at all sure why it wasn't done here. No doubt there was a good reason (or at least an understandable one, such as "we forgot"). But I can't think of any reason that still holds given our current standards, so:

$$
\mathrm{late} > \mathrm{never}
$$

Comment: Yay! Thanks a boatload!

Comment: Thanks Jon! Can we also have the MathJax help link changed to point to [Math's tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), for consistency with the main site? C.f. [this post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/please-link-the-mathjax-help-to-the-meta-math-se-tutorial) and [this mother meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246184/the-mathjax-help-link-should-point-to-a-more-specific-guide)

Comment: @DavidZ: Done. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for this! I've taken the liberty of correctly `mathrm`ing your MathJax, just, because, you know.

Comment: Nice guy! Finally!