# Why you can use mathjax in this website?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, meta

I have just noticed that you can use mathjax in this website, i.e. in Physics meta, but why?

Here for example:

$E=mc^2$

But mathjax is used only when you ask serious question in physics or mathematics and etc..., but serious question in physics should not be asked here on meta, but on physics stack exchange instead.

In physics meta you ask general questions about the physics stack exchange website, but when you ask these questions, you need only html, but not mathjax. You won't ever use mathjax here, so why you can use here mathjax at all?

Comment: Nice. Well, sometimes one might have to explain how mathjax works, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2887/2451) meta post. See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1119/2451) related meta post.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, but not as comment, to my question please? This question, i.e. "how mathjax should works?", shouldn't be asked on meta stack exchange instead?

Comment: Is there any reason why we _shouldn't_ have mathjax here?  I mean, we are discussing a SE site that does rely heavily on Mathjax.  It doesn't seem odd to me that the meta would benefit from access to it.

Comment: Why is this considered as a bad question?

Comment: @ErezZrihen Well, I personally didn't think it was a very good question (hence my comment above), thought I didn't actually vote it down.  It's an additional feature that doesn't do any harm here; so it seems pretty weird to make a question asking why we have it.

Comment: I was just curious, that's all, but you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice. Well, sometimes one might have to explain how mathjax works, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2887/2451) meta post. See also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1119/2451) related meta post.